# how to store/save and restore tensorflow DNNClassifier(No variables to save)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I trained a deep neural network on tensorflow and used to predict some examples but, when I try to save it using [`train.Saver()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) I get the error:
"No variables to save"

Already tried `train.Saver` like this:

```
tf.train.Saver(classi.get_variable_names())
```

But still no luck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

So I ran into the same issue (Estimators don't have save/restore functions yet). I tried savers and [`CheckpointSaver`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/614d4c19fb22df501ba16a3f580f4e3ac1a9df1a/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py#L260) to try and save checkpoints but turns out it's much simpler; just specify the `model_dir` when instantiating the Estimator. This will automatically save checkpoints that can be restored simply by creating an Estimator with the same `model_dir`. Documentation for Estimators [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#DNNClassifier).

Thanks to @ilblackdragon for the solution [here](https://gitter.im/tensorflow/skflow).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code sample from the [tf.variable docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html) that might clarify:

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")
...
# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  ..
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, besides the example you give , i already tried others found on the official documentation having no luck with any of them. With the one you show it says "No variables to save".  Then tried:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn
In the section saving models  and tried using the "save" function i get:
'DNNClassifier' object has no attribute 'save'
So i created it with the depreceated version of TensorflowDNNClassifier and save it ,but when tried to restore it as in the documentation ,it says it doesnt(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) contain a valid model, so reviewed that in the new version it is done with Estimator.restore() , but when you try that, it says that Estimator doesnt contains restore(). So the documentation says actions that cant be executed, as you can see in this chat there are many developers asking the same thing:
https://gitter.im/tensorflow/skflow

Comment: Are you using TF Learn (aka Scikit Flow)?

Comment: Hi Shan, yep im using tf learn, but it seems like a bug as tensorflow developers have told me that the documentation is outdated and they don't know when this functionality will be avaliable:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3340#issuecomment-233142485

https://gitter.im/tensorflow/skflow